# Omnibus GitLab on IP without a domain-name and with custom relative_url_root

Tags: gitlab

I already know that you can download and install gitlab with the omnibus package(easy way). But I'm caught at the configuration of the IP / domain. Because I don't have a domain I want to use my static server IP like this:

Sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure -> "133.713.37.01/gitlab"

Is it even possible to set up gitlab without a domain or am I doing something wrong?

I'm grateful for any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using an IP directly seems to work, since most networking utilities accept either: just add `external_url "http://127.0.0.1"` to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

What does *not* work is adding the `/gitlab` root path to the `external_url`: `gitlab-ctl` says:

```
RuntimeError
------------
Unsupported external URL path: /gitlab
```

Serving from a relative URL root seems to be [simply not implemented on Omnibus GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/ed51ec97401bba955c93e61f8ef860520f745837/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitlab.yml.erb#L24) (since no template variable is inserted there).

You could work around that by modifying all the required configuration files manually as explained in the comment on `gitlab.yml`, but that would really be a lot of manual work and those configs would get overwritten if you reconfigure, so I recommend you request the feature [on the GitLab forum](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general) and send a pull request implementing that.