# Omnibus Gitlab version 7.4.3 at a custom relative_url_root (http://mydomain/gitlab)

Tags: gitlab, server

I have successfully installed older versions of gitlab and hosted them at a location like this:

```
mydomain/gitlab
```

with the new version of gitlab doing all of the config though the gitlab-ctl and via me editing the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb I'm not sure how to achieve this set-up.

I find lots of documentation on stackexchange for older versions of gitlab that did not use gitlab-ctl for configuration but not for the new version. Presently I have gitlab installed and running fine at:

```
mydomain
```

I want to move it to:

```
mydomain/gitlab
```

Anybody know how to do this for version 7.4.3?

Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend you learn precise URL terminology: domain != path ;) will really help you find answers.

Answer (score 1):

Serving from a relative URL root seems to be simply not implemented on Omnibus GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/ed51ec97401bba955c93e61f8ef860520f745837/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitlab.yml.erb#L24 (since no template variable is inserted there)

You could work around that by modifying all the required configuration files manually as explained in the comment on `gitlab.yml`, but that would really be a lot of manual work and those configs would get overwritten if you reconfigure, so I recommend you request the feature at: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general and send a pull request implementing that.

This problem was also raised at: [Omnibus GitLab on IP without a domain-name and with custom relative_url_root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616833/omnibus-gitlab-on-ip-without-a-domain-name-and-with-custom-relative-url-root/26628975#26628975)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same issue this week and set out to find a solution. I'm not all that familiar with RoR so I ended up creating a Bash script to automate the process instead.

Now it'd be a lot nicer if we could just automate all this through /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and hopefully somebody sets that up at some point (maybe someone has that I just can't find?), but in the meantime feel free to use this script as needed. Run as root on a system with a GitLab Omnibus-package installation. Tested on GitLab CE 7.9.0 with Bash 4.2.

[GitLab Relative URL Setter](https://www.mikejhill.com/gitlab/snippets/2)