# Gitlab .deb base url

Tags: http, gitlab

I know it sound similar to other questions, but its not.

Cause I installed it by .deb package not compiled by myself.
Instruction says to change /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
there is 
     external_url = "your url"
which I changed into my domain name
also i found something like 
     gitlab_url="your url" 
which I added also.

I did get halway succes - it works under my wanted url, but all repos still got url with "server-name" instead of domain name.

How can I fix it? :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719704/omnibus-gitlab-version-7-4-3-at-a-custom-relative-url-root-http-mydomain-gitl , covered on my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26721864/895245

Comment: Also I recommend that you don't say things like "I know it sound similar to other questions, but its not." on SO: people might downvote you, honest advice =) Instead, link to the other questions and say why they are not dupes.